# Laravel Backpack not uploading image

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I am attempting to upload a file (country flag) to a simple table countries which should be saved in a "flags" folder of public.

In my add field declaration I have

```
$this->crud->addField([ // image
          'label' => "flag",
          'name' => "flag",
          'type' => 'image',
          'upload' => true,
          'disk' => 'flags', // in case you need to show images from a different disk
          'prefix' => 'flags/'
```

and in the filesystems file I have:

```
'flags' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('flags'),
        'url' => '/flags',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

When I upload it tells me that the field is too short (it is varchar 255) as it seems to want to store the file as data image.

Comment: I have just placed dd($request) and the flag image is being converted:

    "flag" => "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBAIEAfcAMf/////39//v7//n5//e5//e3vf3//f39/fv9/fv7/fn7/fW3vfW1ve9vfe1ve/v9+/v7+/v5+/n5+/e5+/W1u+tte+cpe+Upe+UnO+MnO+ElO97Iefn9+fn7+fn5+fn3ufe3ufOteetteetred7hOd7Ied7GOdzhOdzGOdjc+dja+daa97e797e597e3t7e1t7W1t57hN5zId5zGN5re95jc95S....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take another look at *all* the [instructions for the image field type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-fields#image), in the documentation. Backpack does not take care of the uploading for you - **you need an accessor on your Model**, so you can choose where it's uploaded and how. If you don't do that, Backpack will try to store it as Base64 in your database - which isn't a good idea in most cases.

Example accessor for `flag`:

```
public function setFlagAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "flag";
    $disk = "public_folder";
    $destination_path = "uploads/folder_1/subfolder_3";

    // if the image was erased
    if ($value==null) {
        // delete the image from disk
        \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});

        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
    }

    // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
    {
        // 0. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 90);
        // 1. Generate a filename.
        $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
        // 2. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the path to the database
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $destination_path.'/'.$filename;
    }
}
```